# How to aggregate/compile multiple Excel spreasheets (.csv) into separate sheets in one workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am NOT a programmer - but I need/want to write a command in Excel to aggregate multiple .csv files into separate sheets in one workbook... it runs once, and does copy/paste the contents of one .csv file but then errors out with this error:

```
Runtime error '438':

Object does not support this property or method.
```

I've narrowed it down to this line:

```
'paste it
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Paste
```

But, being that I am new to most all of this, I am unsure what to do. So far I have just been grabbing what seemed like applicable code snippets from around the web.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim wkb As Workbook

'Change this path for your own file location:
strPath = "C:[FILE PATH HERE]"

'this returns an empty string "" if the file cannot be found and will error 
if the folder is incorrect
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

Do While strFile <> ""
 'open the csv file and assign it to a variable so that we can easily 
 reference it later
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)

 'add a new worksheet at the end of the macro workbook to paste into
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

 'get the range and copy it
wkb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
Debug.Print (Sheets.Count)
 'paste it
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Paste

 'close the csv file
wkb.Close

 'find the next file - Dir without parameters will look for the next file in the folder that matches the first Dir call
strFile = Dir
Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub Dougsloop()

     Dim wbk As Workbook
     Dim Filename As String
     Dim path As String
     Dim wsO As Workbook
     Dim StartTime As Double
     Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
     Dim aRR As Variant
     Dim rowC As Long
     Dim colC As Long

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

     StartTime = Timer

     path = "path to folder of files" & "\"
     Filename = Dir(path & "*.csv??")
     Set wsO = ThisWorkbook
     wsO.Sheets(1).Select

     Do While Len(Filename) > 0
         DoEvents
         Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
         aRR = wbk.Sheets(1).UsedRange
         rowC = wbk.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
         colC = wbk.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
         wsO.ActiveSheet.Range(wsO.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), wsO.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowC, colC)).Value2 = aRR
         wbk.Close False
         Filename = Dir
         wsO.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
     Loop

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

     SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
     MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

 End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious - Why not include the final "\" in the `path =`? Why separate it and use `& "\"`?

Comment: @BruceWayne i have had the compiler give me fuss about it before so I just do that out of habit.