# How can I copy data from one worksheet to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I believe this should be very simple for someone to assist me with.

I have two workbooks. One is a workbook that we use as a tracker as it has conditional formatting, etc. setup already I'll refer to this as "file 1"

Each week we get emailed another workbook with the latest and greatest data "file 2".

All I want to do is copy the latest and greatest "file 2" to our working workbook or "file 1".

This is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
 Sub CopyNewData()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\GTF COP June 25 2018.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\CSA Spreadsheets\PW1100 Inventory at CSA_Revised.xlsm")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
x.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").Value = y.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000")

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: MUST it be done with VBA? It is also very simple in Excel itself. Just open both workbooks, right-click on the sheet-tab of the old "file 2" sheet and select `Delete`. Now go to the new "file 2", right-click and select `Move or Copy...`.

Comment: Do you end up with both books open?  Do both books have sheets called `NEOCOP`?  On the two answers so far you've just said "still doesn't work".  How is it not working?  Do both books open ok but the values don't transfer?   Does it give any kind of error message?  Does a giant unicorn fly out of the back of your computer... ok, I've only had that happen once and I don't think it was the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Copy / paste values from one workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374442/vba-copy-paste-values-from-one-workbook-to-another)

Comment: Yes, both workbooks open. Though one of them has the macro in it so I think it's re-opening the same file. Then no pasting happens at all.

Answer (score 0):

First:
`Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\GTF COP June 25 2018.xlsx")`

Then write:

```
x.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").Value2= y.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").Value2
```

Comment: By not working it's not pasting or overwriting the data I want to the destination file. The destination file has the same values as originally started with.

Comment: @NOOB - can you restart your PC and try again?

Comment: @NOOB - write `On Error GoTo 0` after the first line of the code and give it a try. It is up to you whether to do it, thus I guess you have no reason to lie :)

Comment: I just don't understand, this doesn't make any sense. Sorry I keep responding. I figured this would have been much simpler than this has turned out to be. Just opening both workbooks and doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the `.open` :

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\GTF COP June 25 2018.xlsx")
```

**EDIT try this way :**

```
x.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").Copy
y.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Try the second solution and let me know ;)

Comment: Sub CopyNewData()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\GTF COP June 25 2018.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\CSA Spreadsheets\PW1100 Inventory at CSA_Revised.xlsm")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
x.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").Copy
y.Sheets("NEOCOP").Range("A1:AH20000").PasteSpecial


'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub

Comment: It's weird.
I copy/paste your code in a new worbook. I change the path of x and y workbooks and it's working.

Comment: Hmmmm. I've tried that as well. Maybe because it's on a Network drive?

Comment: Probably. We find the reason why the sub didn't work. Check configuration and path of your network drive. Probably add the IP address instead of the letter in the paths.

Comment: It does say that the file is already open. I have the macro stored in the file I wish to paste the data into. Currently there are 5,168 line items. The source file only has 5,127 in it. After the macro runs there's still 5,168. I double checked and it didn't paste the new data anywhere. It's as though it's just opening the file and that's all that it's doing.

Comment: Not sure how to obtain the IP address of a mapped network drive.